# How to join 2 tables in PLSQL in ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a form with dynamic region for purposes of printing. I have a simple PLSQL that works:

```
declare

 cursor c_VYDEJKY is
   select ID, INFO, CUSTOMER_ID
     from VYDEJKY
    where ID = :P54_NEW;
 
    begin
      sys.htp.p('<ul>');
      for a in c_VYDEJKY loop
        sys.htp.p('<li>' || a.ID || ' (' || a.CUSTOMER_ID || ')</li>' );
       end loop;
      sys.htp.p('</ul>');
    end;
```

but when I try to join another table with LEFT JOIN or WHERE clause it doesnt work:

```
declare

 cursor c_VYDEJKY is
   select v.ID, v.INFO, v.CUSTOMER_ID, c.CUSTOMERNAME
     from VYDEJKY v, CUSTOMERS c
    where v.ID = :P54_NEW
    AND v.CUSTOMER_ID > c.ID;

 
begin
  sys.htp.p('<ul>');
  for a in c_VYDEJKY loop
    sys.htp.p('<li> ID VÝDEJKY  :' ||  a.ID ||'</li>' );
    sys.htp.p('<li> POZNÁMKY  :' ||  a.INFO ||'</li>' );
    sys.htp.p('<li> POZNÁMKY  :' ||  c.CUSTOMERNAME ||'</li>' );
   end loop;
  sys.htp.p('</ul>');
end;
```

I am getting following error on c.CUSTOMERNAME

```
ORA-06550: line 15, column 39: PLS-00201: identifier 'C.CUSTOMERNAME' must be declared
```

Can someone please point to where I am makiing a mistake. I am really just starting with PLSQL.

Thank you,
JJ

Answer (score 2):

Within the `for` loop, the prefix for the column names refers to the cursor row variable (`for a in`) not the table alias, so you need to specify:

```
a.CUSTOMERNAME
```